# Убедительная просьба

Tags: грамотная-речь

Наверное, все видели объявления типа: "Убедительная просьба: место кондуктора не занимать". Но почему эта просьба более убедительна чем та, которая себя таковой не провозглашает?

Ясно, что здесь есть ошибка, только вот какая? Логическая? Речевая? И какого типа?

Comment: >Вот уже шесть словарей "неправильных"  
  
Только с Ваших слов.
Одно дело сказать "он просил убедительно", дугое - начинать свое послание с бессмысленного "Убедительная просьба".

Comment: >Я всегда аргументирую свое мнение ссылками  

Плохо аргументируете. 

>Ничего личного, просто добрый совет : поменьше ненависти, побольше добрых эмоций и понимания... Читайте классические тексты.

Взаимно.

Comment: Дерзкий, это Вы удлили мои комментарии?

Comment: Дерзкий, это Вы удалили мои комментарии?

Он, конечно. Больше никому это в голову не придет.
Я его комментарии сознательно не удалял никогда (разве по технической ошибке), а он мои - регулярно. "Места" сейчас, кстати, всем хватает.  
  
Плюньте. Связываться - себе дороже.

Comment: Ясно. Хотя обидно, что с тобой вот так вот. 
А я вот только свои могу удалять...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ясно, что здесь есть ошибка, только вот какая? Логическая? Речевая? И какого типа?

Я не буду придерживаться "утвержденного" списка ошибок. 
Я бы отнёс данную ошибку к риторическим, хотя во  фразе и нет нарушения грамматики. 
Просто нарушаются законы риторики.

Смысл в том, что говорящий полагает, что от его довеска в виде "убедительной" просьба становится то ли более действенной (убедительной), то ли более вежливой... В принципе все опять восходит к канцеляриту.

У Чуковского, кажется, в "Живой как жизнь" есть что-то на эту тему. Но искать не хочется. Писано, как понимаете, более полувека назад, времена и отношение к тому, что некогда считалось ошибкой, меняются...

Comment: Я вот чего подумал. А вот интересно было бы услышать от апологетов "убедительной просьбы", какой смысл они в неё, эту самую "убедительную" вкладывают - и нем она отличается от просьбы  просто и просьбы неубедительной. 

По мне так - глупость несусветная. Пусть уж просимый решает убедительна ли просьба просящего, а для этого просьба должна быть вежливой, нижайшей, покорнейшей, коленопреклоненной - какой угодно, в зависимости от исторической эпохи. Но никак не "убедительной".

Answer (score 1):

Глупый бессмысленный оборот. Почему она должна убеждать? Тогда следует дописать веское обоснование для убеждения, которое может и не убедить. Мне кажется, что ошибка смысловая или логическая. Другое дело - настоятельная или большая...

Comment: А чем "настоятельная" лучше?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, чисто логически это глупый бессмысленный оборот, но он призывает обратить на данную просьбу несколько большее внимание, чем на обычную.)))

Answer (score 0):

Присоединяюсь к предыдущему ответу, только замечу, что часто это используют люди, для которых написание обращений не всегда профессиональная обязанность, а необходимость, в силу обстоятельств. Сравнимо  со спецификой "юридического языка", на котором не все могут писать простые обыватели свои иски, обращения и т.п.. Мы просто воспринимаем такие обороты " на слух", "

Answer (score -1):

Это просто неправильное воспроизведение словосочетания "Настоятельная просьба". Ошибка передающаяся как вирус.